# Backup Hyper-V VMs

Tags: backup, hyper-v

i'm looking for an alternative for Hyperoo, one of the best backup solutions for VMs backup..
I tried many softwares, like Veem, Iperius, Altaro, Acronis ecc but everyone use Microsoft checkpoints and create AVHDX files, sometimes it happens that the backup has some problems and the avhdx remains open, I find myself forced to merge that punt hoping everything goes well.
All these programs make a false incrementally backup.
Even with every small modification the vhdx changes a little. The backup program checks that the virtual machine has changed and makes a full backup.
Hyperoo creates one full vhdx file and then many rollback files, one file each day.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want safety and performance for your Hyper-V VM backups. Backup and restore is a stressful experience. As you mentioned the solutions use the Hyper-V checkpoint technologies and I don't know something else.

We tested a lot backup tools and end up with Veeam. Usually the backup and restore works. Unfortunately it put a lot weight on the infrastructure during backup (storage is slow..) and sometimes the backups fails because of this. To evade this we setup fixed periods outside the work time. Keep in mind that we use the Backup only for server VMs (not VDI).

I would recommend Veeam as backup solution, but maybe you can take a look at Commvault.(https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=31493.htm)

Greetings.